# Angular 4 + node js

Tags: express, angular4

Возможно такой вопрос уже был. В чем дело хотелось бы узнать. Как передавать сгенерированую Angukal страницу в отображение в серверной части написаной на express.js. Может посоветуете что почитать или на темку направите, буду благодарен

Comment: Сформируйте, пожалуйста, правильно вопрос.

Comment: Постараюсь обрисовать ситуацию. Существует идея сайта. На котором есть 3 страницы. И соответсвенно между ним есть роутинг, который построен на express.js. Одна из этих html страниц должна динамически изменятся. Тоесть должна быть сделана на Angular . Вопрос я не совсем понимаю как из всей кучи файлов который генерирует Angular CLI взять и передать что то что бы сервер мог передавать эту страницу

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы про трансфер состояния то:

https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-5-universal-with-transfer-state-using-angular-cli-19fe1e1d352c